# asp.net webforms, why do I have to use fully qualified names despite having a using statement?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I should start by saying I'm new to ASP.NET, coming to it from a winforms background, so I might be missing something blindingly obvious.

The issue I'm having is that despite having added a using statement in my code behind file:

```
using Core.Business.Library.Crew;
```

I am having to fully declare my classes to get them to compile and for intellisense to work, e.g.

```
businessObject = Core.Business.Library.Crew.CrewMemberEdit.GetCrewMemberEdit(id)
```

I'm guessing there's maybe something obvious I'm missing?  The library classes are in their own project within the solution and that project is referenced in the WebApplication project.

Comment: Oh the shame... yes, that is exactly the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pages in ASP.NET are classes, so change the name of your page to something besides `CrewMemberEdit` and you will not have to fully qualify your `GetCrewMemberEdit(id)` method call anymore.

Since the names were the same, the compiler could not figure out which class you wanted to use unless you fully qualified the name.

Comment: I normally stick 'Control' on the end of the name to avoid this sort of thing, this is the danger of following example code you don't fully understand!

Comment: @tom_redox - we have all done it, but that is a good idea to put a name at the end to differentiate them. Feel free to up-vote the answer if you wish. :-)